# How to make a js fullscreen toggle

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a button that will toggle my website to go full screen. I am not sure about how to?

Comment: Use the power of search

Answer (score 5):

look what a little bit of searching brought up from [google](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen(); 
    }
  }
}
```